# std::out_of_range at memory location

Tags: c++

this block gives me the error message std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0013f59c.
the problem comes from the 3 middle lines ( where I have put the asterisks ) . Before the code worked perfectly. I also checked personally that every line contained correctly the first 6 characters.

```
if (openfile.is_open() && newfile.is_open())
{
      while (! openfile.eof())
     {   
                   getline(openfile, originaldata);
                   string day(originaldata,6,2);           *
                   string month(originaldata,4,2);             *
                   string year(originaldata,0,4);              *
                   string data=day+"/"+month+"/"+year;  
     }
}
```

Comment: So what's in your file? What is the value of originaldata when it throws an exception?

Comment: To prevent these errors, you should validate `originaldata` before assuming details about it.  This is called *robustness*.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
if (openfile.is_open() && newfile.is_open())
{
     while (getline(openfile, originaldata))
     {
                   string day(originaldata,6,2);
                   string month(originaldata,4,2);
                   string year(originaldata,0,4);
                   string data=day+"/"+month+"/"+year;  
     }
}
```

Using eof is almost always wrong because eof tells you why the **last** read failed, it does not tell you that the **next** read will fail. So if you are going to use it then use it after getline not before.

Comment: It tells you if the last read involved attempting to extract the end-of-file. Not necessarily a failure.

Comment: I still have that problem

Comment: OK, so what is the value of originaldata when you get the exception? Is it a blank line or a line that is too short like Drew Dormann suggests? I did ask this question originally, it's basic information to help you understand what the problem is.

Comment: I had read your question but I had specified that I had already personally checked all the file. Just to avoid you think I ignored your request. I have found the real problem: below the file there is an empty line. It is the space between the data and the lower border of the .txt file. I deleted that line and the code works. Now the question is: how to prevent my code from treating an empty line like something to read ?

Comment: For isntance, `while (getline(openfile, originaldata) && originaldata.size() > 0)`. On the other point, checking the file is no substitute for finding out the actual values of variables in your program when it runs. It's really common for variables to get values we didn't expect (as happened in this case). You should spend the time learning how to use your compilers *debugger*. This will save you loads of time very quickly.

Comment: @alwaystudent Sorry the code above is rubbish, try `while (getline(openfile, originaldata)) { if (originaldata.size() > 0) { ... } }`

Comment: @john You are perfectly right, John, and thanks a lot for your help. Anyway getline (openfile,originaldata) must be inserted between your while and the subsequent if. As you correctly pointed out we must check the NEXT line not the last. We all made that mistake.  Now everything works perfectly. Thank you a lot, John

Answer (score 2):

Your input file probably contains a blank line, which `getline` will read, producing an empty string.

Or a malformed line is too short.

Consider using this.

```
  while ( getline(openfile, originaldata) && originaldata.length() > 8 )
```

Using the `getline` as a conditional in your `while` will let your code gracefully fail if *any* fail bit is set in `openfile`.  Not just EOF.

Comment: the code keeps giving the same error